# How can I find if my machine is in Amazon cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I have an instance booted up. Is there a check that I can use to find if this instance is in Amazon cloud.

I know I can query the Amazon meta data store like this and if this check is positive I am in amazon cloud or not otherwise.

```
    curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

But are there any kernel parameters or options that can tell me if this is in amazon?

Answer (score 0):

you might check the public IP of your instance: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701